# Execute a command line with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

How to execute a command line using nodejs. I am trying to install a module in local by --save in my angular project using visual studio code editor but the script is not working.Anyone can find the mistake where i did?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `child = exec("npm install --save " + module_ins`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to concatenate your variable with the command and add the path of your angular project to the `cwd` argument:

```
child = exec("npm install --save" + module_ins,
{
  cwd: '/path_to_angular_project'
},
function (error, stdout, stderr) {
...
```

Or using [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
child = exec(`npm install --save ${module_ins}`,
{
  cwd: '/path_to_angular_project'
},
function (error, stdout, stderr) {
...
```

Comment: Getting error : stderr: npm WARN saveerror ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\users\michel\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\package.json' npm warn enoent

Comment: Installing in vs code but i want to install in my angular project..How do it?

Comment: You must specify the path of your angular project using `cwd` argument

Comment: cwd?? I do not know how to set my project path..please ping me the script

Comment: Can i give like this?  var pathname="c://mamp/htdocs/projects/treemaintain";   child = exec("npm install --save" + module_ins,
{
  cwd: pathname
},

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197347/discussion-between-fraction-and-sitharth).

Comment: It should be like this: cwd: '/c://mamp/htdocs/projects/treemaintain'     ??

Comment: Fraction: I am waiting for you answer